# Custom domain name for api , domain already exists in the stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cloudformation

I want to create a custom api for my gateway I'm following this tutorial , https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-domainname.html

I pre createed my certificate and assigned it a domain in my stack

> ```
> myDomainName:
>   Type: AWS::ApiGateway::DomainName
>   Properties:
>     DomainName: "test.mydomain.com"
>     CertificateArn: "valid certificate"
> ```

now I try and redeploy that stack and get an error

> myDomainName test.mydomain.com already exists in stack

is there a  way to check if the domain already exists on stack redeploy ?

Comment: How did you solve this?

Comment: You can use customresource for this, create a custom resource backed lambda which checks for the existence of the domain name and returns as output true or false. Based on this value, you can use a conditional in cloudformation which will decide whether you want to create or not.

Comment: The other way to do this would be to delete the resource manually before re-deploying the stack, and your template will create the domain again. This has the added bonus that if you comment out the ApiGateway::DomainName from the stack, the domain will be deleted by CF.

Comment: try using DomainNameOptions instead of DomainName and use it in the restAPI construct.
This works for me